# Why do cats lick my toes?

Tags: cats, psychology

This has happened with 3-4 cats I've came to own in the past years.

They rub themselves against my feet, and if I'm barefoot/wearing flip flops, they start to lick my toes.

Why do they do that?

Comment: Many cats react to strong concentrations of human scent by wanting to rub against it, hence their infatuation with shoes and washcloths.   Maybe your toes smell especially like you. Or smell like a kitten they should groom. Or maybe they're just looking for salt. You could try some experiments...

Comment: Cats used to love shoving their faces into my grandfather's armpits. Some folks just smell interesting.

Comment: I've wondered if cats like the salt from our sweat.

Answer (score 4):

You could just have that kind of scent that cats like. Just like cat nip. Either that of they feel psychologically secure when you are around them, making them want to lick the closest thing to them (your toes).

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple explanations I can think of.  The first is some cats tend to lick when they rub on you.  So it may be just that they're rubbing on your feet because your feet are easily accessible, then licking naturally.  The other is that some cats are attracted to shoes.  I've had cats that like rubbing on and playing with shoes in particular.  It may be they are particularly attracted to your feet as a result.

Answer (score 0):

They like to lick your feet because they know that you're it's owner and that they will feel more safe around you, just like when you were little, you would never run away from your parents! Cats are the same thing, they are like your younger brother/sister

Answer (score 0):

Well cats are attracted to our shoes because that's where most of our sweat goes during the day, so they carry our scent . They like to put their heads off in the shoes and put their scent on it. Our feet carry most of our scent so your kitty is probably just showing you affection and getting some salt as well lol

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange Mary, do you have any sources or websites that support your answer?